# Is there a free Windows Registry Listener?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I've encountered issues with an application having multiple places where it **can** save certain settings but it appears that they are sometimes not sticking.

I'm fairly sure they are being stored in the Windows Registry and thus I'm curious if there is a **free** tool that "monitors" / listens to writes/edits to the registry.

Ideally using such a tool would help me identify which parts of the application are correctly storing the settings and which are not (for whatever reason).

For the record I don't need to intercept/block or alter the edits, I just want to know when and where they happen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) will do exactly what you want (and more).

You may also find [SpyMe Tools](http://www.lcibrossolutions.com/spyme_tools.htm) interesting.  It lets you create before/after snapshots and compare them to see what changed.

Comment: I've never used SpyMe Tools, but I have used Regshot to do the exact same thing and it works great. http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/

Comment: SpyMe Tools will also monitor the filesystem.  The only annoying part is that you can't create snapshots for both fs & registry at once, but that's a relatively minor complaint.

Answer (score -1):

I use Process Monitor, I've used it for diagnosing bad application behaviour, checkout the article on my blog which may help you use it http://joelmansford.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/ms-dynamics-crm-40-client-configuration-wizard-fails-with-%E2%80%9Coutlook-is-not-set-as-the-default-mail-client%E2%80%9D-on-windows-server-2008-x64/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.